# microtime showing 1.52214531583E+12

Tags: php, time, microtime

I am using `round(microtime(true) * 1000);` for generating current timestamp in 13 digits.

But it is not returning me correct 13 digit values instead it return something like this:

> 1.52214531583E+12

which is not useful in my case.

How can i convert this to 13 digit number

Comment: why it is down voted ?

Comment: Probably mainly because “what are you even talking about?” -> https://3v4l.org/HLvlH (If there’s any special circumstances, like you’d still be running this on a 32 bit system, you should mention those.)